# Compare data for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables A and B like below

Table A

```
+---------+--------+
|  query  | status |
+---------+--------+
| number1 | solved |
+---------+--------+
```

table B

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id |  query  | status  |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 | number1 | started |
|  2 | number1 | working |
|  3 | number1 | solved  |
+----+---------+---------+
```

how do i check whether the latest status of table B is equal to status of Table A

i have tried first getting latest status for table 2 but i am unable to get so

```
select number ,max(status),max(id) 
from Table B 
group by number 
order by max(id) asc
```

Comment: First you need to group table B by query and get the max id, then join with table A and check the status.

Comment: hi @Martin i have edited the query above

Comment: Can you please edit your question so that the table and column names in your query match the names in the sample data... It will make it a lot easier to understand

Comment: done @Nick please refer

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from A a
    inner join B b on b.query = a.query
    inner join 
         (select max(id) id, query
          from B
          group by query) gq on gq.id = b.id and gq.query = b.query
where a.status = b.status
```

Comment: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'gq.status' in 'where clause'

Comment: fixed, it should be b.status

Comment: can we write an update query if the status is not same from same select query

Comment: @munch2, not getting you... try to post another question with more details

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution relying on sorting by ID and getting only first row in a sub-query. It will only returns rows  that has a match between the two tables.

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN (SELECT query, status 
      FROM tableB
      ORDER BY ID desc 
      LIMIT 1) b ON a.query = b.query AND a.status = b.status
```

Answer (score 0):

use join and subquery

```
select a.* from
 tablea a join
(
select * from table_name t1
where id =( select max(id) from table_name t2 where t1.query=t2.query)
) b join on a.query=b.query and a.status=b.status
```